# Is it possible to set "this" in anonymous function?

Tags: c#, anonymous-function

I've got a function,

```
public SharpQuery Each(Action<int, HtmlNode> function)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _context.Count; ++i)
        function(i, _context[i]);
    return this;
}
```

Which calls the passed in function for each element of the context. Is it possible to set what "this" refers to inside `Action<int, HtmlNode> function`?

For example,

```
sharpQuery.Each((i, node) => /* `this` refers to an HtmlNode here */);
```

Comment: Wanting a bit of JavaScript to make its way into C#? :)

Comment: @Chaos: I can live without it... but I'm trying to mimic a certain JS library as closely as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

Well, yes, if the Action was created in such a scope where 'this' was available and bound in a closure -- but transparently: no.

Pass in all needed information or make sure it's captured/available in the Action itself. There are other hacks like thread-locals, etc. Best avoided.

Answer (score 5):

With a slight change in the function, you can achieve the desired effect.

```
public SharpQuery Each(Action<MyObject, int, HtmlNode> function)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _context.Count; ++i)
        function(this, i, _context[i]);
    return this;
}
```

Then you could write your function call like so:

```
sharpQuery.Each((self, i, node) => /* do something with `self` which is "this" */);
```

Note: The anonymous function will only have access to public members however.  If the anonymous function was defined within the class, it will have access to protected and private members as usual.

e.g.,

```
class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(int i)
    {
        this.Number = i;
    }

    public int Number { get; private set; }
    private int NumberPlus { get { return Number + 1; } }

    public void DoAction(Action<MyObject> action)
    {
        action(this);
    }

    public void PrintNumberPlus()
    {
        DoAction(self => Console.WriteLine(self.NumberPlus));  // has access to private `NumberPlus`
    }
}

MyObject obj = new MyObject(20);
obj.DoAction(self => Console.WriteLine(self.Number));     // ok
obj.PrintNumberPlus();                                    // ok
obj.DoAction(self => Console.WriteLine(self.NumberPlus)); // error
```

Comment: I guess you can think of it as an "anonymous extension method."

Comment: +1 But it seems that OP wants to perfectly simulate jQuery in C#. You solution makes the `.Each` method differ from the one in jQuery. Anyway it's the best solution I can think of.

Comment: Actually I wanted "this" to refer to the HtmlNode, not MyObject. It isn't really needed as I've already passed it in... but I'm trying trying to copy some functionality from jQuery. I guess the answer is "no".

Comment: @Mark: The answer is no. "this" in JS is much more freely used than that in C#. I'm afraid you need to add one note in your SharpQuery spec saying `"this" keyword is not supported in anonymous functions`.

Comment: @Mark: Of course replace `MyObject` with the appropriate type, I wasn't sure what `this` was in your code. Unfortunately the keyword `this` cannot be used outside of the context of an instance.  And even then, it cannot be reassigned.  This would be the closest way to do so in C# I think.  Otherwise there is no notion of `this` outside of an instance.  Unfortunately you can't do it in exactly the same way as jQuery, this would be a compromise.

Comment: @Jeff: I mean I didn't want to pass in a reference to my type at all, but I wanted "this" to refer to something entirely different (a different context, not of my type). Specifically, "this" in the former context would be a SharpQuery instance, in the latter (inside the anon. func) it would be an HtmlNode. I was hoping maybe we could do something like add a method to the HtmlNode instance and then invoke it so it had the proper context, but... that's okay. I can live without it.

Comment: @Mark: Ah ok.  Well you know your options now should you decide to do something like this.  ;)  I have a vague understanding of javascript and know what you mean.  Unfortunately it's just not possible.